# Should we create the tag open-source

Tags: discussion, tags

In the wake of another recent question about tags ([Specific tags for subfields: desirable?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5406/specific-tags-for-subfields-desirable?cb=1)) and the suggestion in the answer to discuss new tags here first, there was a new tag created here today, [open-source](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source). A quick search for the term "open source" finds [over 700](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22open+source%22) results. While I generally think that we have already quite a lot of tags, this tag might actually be a sensible one to create, as there are alreay a ton of questions related to open source solutions in the context of academia. Or is there another, existing tag that [open-source](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) could be a synomy of?

What do you think?

Comment: 1. A search for ["open source" is:q](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22open+source%22+is%3Aq), which is supposed to pick out only questions, finds a more modest 241 hits. 2. Even so, there is substantial variation in topics, so I think it's unlikely they should all be given the same tag. I thus think any proposal for such a tag should define the scope of the tag.

Comment: @Anyon Faair enough, but even if only half of those question can be gathered under an open source tag, this tag will still have substantially more questions under it than the bottom half of the existing tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a strong opinion, but given the silence so far, I'll take a stand....

**Sure, let's do it.** (Just one guy's opinion, let's see how others vote on this answer).

Perhaps the scope of the tag could be:

> Queries on the benefits and drawbacks of contributing to or using open source tools, and advice for doing so.